# What is the different between parent: relative child: absolute with child:relative?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I got that If I use child's position as relative, I can move child's position attached to parent. like this:

```
#child{
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;  }
```

Sometimes I see that parent's position is relative, and child's position is absolute. like this.

```
 #parent{
  position: relative;

  }
 #child{
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  }
```

But what's different with this two?

Answer (score 0):

Both are positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor.

The difference being, child with `position: absolute` is removed from the normal flow.